# Best way to define element to render in ts file in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I want to make a function, in component file (let's say `example.component.ts`), which will return html element to render.

I tried to do it in the way it's written in html, so:

`example.component.ts`

```
  renderSomething() {
      const data = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
      return `<div>{{data[0]}}</div>`;
  }
```

and in `example.component.html`:

```
  <span>
    {{renderSomething()}}
  </span>
```

I wanted to get:

```
  <span>
    <div>zero</div>
  </span>
```

but instead I receive:

```
  <span>
    <div>{{data[0]}}</div> // <-- this liretally renders in html
  </span>
```

I've also tried this:

```
  renderSomething() {
      const data = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
      return `<div>${data[0]}</div>`;
  }
```

but the the "`<div>`" is also rendered in browser as text, and I want it to render as html element.

So my question is - what is the standard way to write such a code?

Or maybe it can't be done and I need to create separate component for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your renderSomething method to

```
 renderSomething() {
      const data = ['zero', 'one', 'two'];
      return `<div>${data[0]}</div>`;
  }
```

Then in html

```
<div [innerHtml]="renderSomething()"></div>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cn7saz)

Comment: Thanks, works :) I'll wait a bit with marking this as accepted answer, because maybe someone will bring some other solution, which would be better / more common.

Comment: @pbialy glad to it helped

Answer (score 0):

@jitender has added the correct solution for this approach but in my experience, this may not be the best approach to update the DOM with data. For example, if you will not receive data from renderSomething() or may receive incorrect data if you are populating data array by maybe a network call. A good approach would be bind the data to be displayed which can also be checked in HTML of verification, example:

In HTML

```
<div>{{ selection }}</div>
```

In component.ts

```
data = []
selection: any;

  getData() {
    // get data array from API and populate it
    // after data array is populated:
    this.selection = data[0];
  }
```

You can call `getData()` by say on a button click.

Comment: did you check data is hardcoded in op question and he need to add html from ts file

Comment: I know, I just shared my approach.

Comment: I think that this doens't answer my question. With your approach I won't render `div` html element, I will have "<div>" as text.

Comment: You wont have <div> as text because it will be parsed by the browser. You can see the sample here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckuxzx

Comment: You can see in the example that the text is loaded 2 seconds after the component loads and <div> is not shown as plain text.

Comment: @Yash I want to set html elements in js file. So I need to, in your example, change the string from getData to `<div>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</div>`, and I want it to be rendered as html div element, but it renders as text.

Comment: That is right. As I mentioned, I just shared my approach which is, a more general approach to update DOM. @jitender's answer definitely solves your issue.

Comment: My approach is that, don't return HTML elements from component, just update their values/